# How to rescale subMorph when the container does?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, squeak, morphic

I am exploring Squeak, release 5.2 in MacOS.

I am drawing lines (PolygonMorph) inside a RectangleMorph 'r'. When I translate 'r' the lines translate but when I rescale 'r' the lines do not rescale.

Run the snipped below. Then with the Halo translate and resize the rectangle 'r'. You will see line 'p' get translated but not rescaled.

```
r := RectangleMorph new.
"[Pharo] r:= Morph.new."
r extent: 500@500.
r openInWindow. 

p := PolygonMorph 
        vertices: {(r left)@(r top). (r right)@(r bottom)}
        color: Color white borderWidth: 2 borderColor: Color white.

r addMorph: p.
```

How can I get 'p' to rescale ?

bye

Comment: May I suggest you to explore a bit more on your own? Debug `p scale: 1.2` to see why it does scale. And then debug `r scale: 1.2` to see why it does not scale. This should give you some insight.

Comment: After your message I discovered CMD+D :/ It will take me a lot of time to unravel all of this. If you can give me a hand and tell me how things are and if I can at all get what I ask I would be grateful.

Comment: I didn't mean to be enigmatic, I just told you what I would do. Anyway, if I have a chance, I'll download Squeak and give it a try myself. No promise though, so keep debugging. That's the most efficient way to learn.

Comment: Ok, I will try to get what I can from the debugger, I am very new to SmallTalk. I tested the script in Pharo (7.0.3 MacOS) as well, similar problem.

Comment: As you move the resize halo, the rectangle will receive `doGrow:with:`, which in turn sends `setExtentFromHalo:`, which only sends `extent:`. So, if you create a subclass of `RectangleMorph` which, besides changing its `extent`, changes the `extents` of all its submorphs (proportionally), you should get the effect you are looking for (by using the new subclass instead of a `RectangleMorph`).

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer when it answers your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 4):

This may not be the complete answer you are looking for, but sharing what I did, might help you to make some progress with your interesting problem.

1. I'm not a Squeak (or Pharo) user, so I downloaded Squeak from the web.
2. Pasted your code in a Workspace and executed it.
3. Reproduced the behavior you observed: resizing the rectangle has no effect on its polygon sub-morph.
4. Popped up the rectangle menu and saw the 'add halo' item.
5. Wrote `'add halo'` somewhere and right-clicked to bring all methods with that literal.
6. Found `#addHalo:` as the associated message to the menu item.
7. Inserted a `halt` to debug `#addHalo:`.
8. Cmd+clicked to bring the halo and debugged until I found that the resize handle would send
   `addGrow:with:` to the morph.
9. Then I saw that `addGrow:with:` sends `setExtentFromHalo:` and that this sends `extent:`.

My conclusion is that you would need a new subclass of `RectangleMorph` that resizes all its sub-morphs, proportionally, when it receives `setExtentFromHalo:`. Something on the lines of

```
ScalableRectangleMorph >> #setExtentFromHalo: aPoint
  current := self extent.
  super setExtentFromHalo: aPoint.
  scale := self extent - current / current.
  self submorphsDo: [:m | m extent: (m extent * scale) rounded]
```

Give this a try (I haven't), and let us know how it went.

Comment: Thank you a lot @Leandro for explaining how you analyzed the problem ! Tomorrow morning i will try ! bye.

Comment: Setting a new LayoutPolicy for its submorphs should be enough